# Odoo 13 fields/bottons translations

Tags: odoo

[How I do translate the same fields and buttons in odoo 13 WEBSITE FORM module, like "Choose file" and text in the field "No file chosen".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvxKe.jpg)
 [sample][2]

Thanks :)

Comment: I guess, this is related to the browser & the operating system locale, not related to odoo. is such field auto rendered from odoo ??

Comment: probably depends on the locale, I will try to change the locale. Thanks for the post

Answer (score 0):

If it is in your model and you may want it in different languages
you can

1. go To setting in odoo 13
2. menue Translations
3. export file
4. select language and FileFormat
5. csv and Export
6. download it
7. and add to projekt in pycharm forexample photo

[image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG63S.png)
[image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM98S.png)

If you just want one place and in a specific language:
string="every things for show button" xml:

```
<button name="choose file" string="show file" type="action"/>
```